# Activate / Install a Solution in Sharepoint Online (Sitecollection -> Webtemplate)

Tags: sharepoint, office365, solution, sharepoint-online

I try with the help of a Webrequest, a Button in Sharepoint Online to trigger.

The first Errro-Code:

Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

```
$solutionId = Get-SPOSolutionId -solutionName $solutionName

# Queries the solution's page
$operation = ""
if($activate) 
{ 
    $operation = "ACT" 
} 
else 
{ 
    $operation = "DEA" 
}

$solutionPageUrl = Join-SPOParts -Separator '/' -Parts $context.Site.Url, "/_catalogs/solutions/forms/activate.aspx?Op=$operation&ID=$solutionId"

$c
if ($context.Credentials -ne $null)
{
    $authCookieValue = $context.Credentials.GetAuthenticationCookie($context.Url)
    # Create fed auth Cookie
    $fedAuth = new-object System.Net.Cookie
    $fedAuth.Name = "FedAuth"
    $fedAuth.Value = $authCookieValue.TrimStart("SPOIDCRL=")
    $fedAuth.Path = "/"
    $fedAuth.Secure = $true
    $fedAuth.HttpOnly = $true
    $fedAuth.Domain = (New-Object System.Uri($context.Url)).Host

    # Hookup authentication cookie to request
    $cookieContainer.Add($fedAuth)

    $request.CookieContainer = $cookieContainer
}
else
{
    # No specific authentication required
    $request.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
}

$request.ContentLength = 0

$response = $request.GetResponse()

    # decode response
    $strResponse = $null
    $stream = $response.GetResponseStream()
    if (-not([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($response.Headers["Content-Encoding"])))
    {
        if ($response.Headers["Content-Encoding"].ToLower().Contains("gzip"))
        {
            $stream = New-Object System.IO.Compression.GZipStream($stream, [System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Decompress)
        }
        elseif ($response.Headers["Content-Encoding"].ToLower().Contains("deflate"))
        {
            $stream = new-Object System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream($stream, [System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Decompress)
        }
    }

    # get response string
    $sr = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($stream)

        $strResponse = $sr.ReadToEnd()

    $sr.Close()
    $sr.Dispose()

    $stream.Close()

    $inputMatches = $strResponse | Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern "<input.+?\/??>" | select -Expand Matches

    $inputs = @{}

    # Look for inputs and add them to the dictionary for postback values
    foreach ($match in $inputMatches)
    {
        if (-not($match[0] -imatch "name=\""(.+?)\"""))
        {
            continue
        }
        $name = $matches[1]

        if(-not($match[0] -imatch "value=\""(.+?)\"""))
        {
            continue
        }
        $value = $matches[1]

        $inputs.Add($name, $value)
    }

    # Lookup for activate button's id
    $searchString = ""
    if ($activate) 
    {
        $searchString = "ActivateSolutionItem"
    }
    else
    {
        $searchString = "DeactivateSolutionItem"
    }

    $match = $strResponse -imatch "__doPostBack\(\&\#39\;(.*?$searchString)\&\#39\;"
    $inputs.Add("__EVENTTARGET", $Matches[1])

$response.Close()
$response.Dispose()

# Format inputs as postback data string, but ignore the one that ends with iidIOGoBack
$strPost = ""
foreach ($inputKey in $inputs.Keys)
{
    if (-not([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($inputKey)) -and -not($inputKey.EndsWith("iidIOGoBack")))
    {
        $strPost += [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString($inputKey) + "=" + [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString($inputs[$inputKey]) + "&"
    }
}
$strPost = $strPost.TrimEnd("&")

$postData = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($strPost);

# Build postback request
$activateRequest = $context.WebRequestExecutorFactory.CreateWebRequestExecutor($context, $solutionPageUrl).WebRequest
$activateRequest.Method = "POST"
$activateRequest.Accept = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*"
if ($context.Credentials -ne $null)
{
    $activateRequest.CookieContainer = $cookieContainer
}
else
{
    # No specific authentication required
    $activateRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
}
$activateRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
$activateRequest.ContentLength = $postData.Length
$activateRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)";
$activateRequest.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache";
$activateRequest.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip, deflate";
$activateRequest.Headers["Accept-Language"] = "fr-FR,en-US";

# Add postback data to the request stream
$stream = $activateRequest.GetRequestStream()
    $stream.Write($postData, 0, $postData.Length)
    $stream.Close();
$stream.Dispose()

# Perform the postback
$response = $activateRequest.GetResponse()
$response.Close()
$response.Dispose()
```

Context

```
    $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($xmlContent.sites.site.Url) 

$context.Credentials = $spoCredentials
$context.RequestTimeOut = 500 * 60 * 10;
$web = $context.Web
$site = $context.Site   
$context.Load($web)
$context.Load($site)
try
{
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

$spoCredentials

```
$spoCredentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($xmlContent.sites.site.Username, $SecurePassword)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your external endpoint in the manifest file. you need to add the url of the endpoint so the app has the permissions to access external endpoint.

Here is a link with code sample how to execute/query external endpoints and other sources such as: web app, host app or site collections...etc.

http://blog.ctp.com/2014/06/23/data-access-in-sharepoint-hosted-apps/